# <enter> stops working on keypress

Tags: javascript

html:

```
<div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10">
    {{ form_widget(experienceForm.description, {
        'attr': {
            'class': 'form-control field-max-length field-max-length field-line-length',
            'rows': 6
        }
     })}}
</div>

handleChangeLineCounter = function() {
    $('.field-line-length').keyup(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var countLineNum = (this.value.match(/\n/g)||[]).length;
        console.log(countLineNum);
        checkEnterKey ($(this), 7, countLineNum);
    });
}

function checkEnterKey (getVarName, maxLine, countLine) {
    var msg2 = maxLine - countLine +' lignes restantes,';
    if ((maxLine - countLine) === 1 || (maxLine - countLine) === 0) {
        msg2 = maxLine - countLine +' ligne restante,';
    }

    getVarName.keypress(function(e) {
        if(e.which === 13) {
            if ((maxLine - countLine) < 1) {
                return false;
            }
            else if ((maxLine - countLine) > 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    });

    $('.counter-msg-2').remove();
    getVarName.after('<span class="counter-msg-2 m-r-5"><span class="counter_msg_2">' + msg2 + '</span></span>');
}
```

From the above code, in the function `checkEnterKey()`, when (`maxLine - countLine`) reaches 0, I press delete key or backspace key then press enter key again, the key stops working.
On the contrary if (`maxLine - countLine`) does not reach 0, I press delete key or backspace key then press enter key again, the key works.
How can I make the enter key work when I reach `(maxLine - countLine) = 0` ?

Comment: Have you tried changing to `maxLine - countLine < 0` when returning false?

Comment: I did, and the problem still occurs, I tried <= 0, I even changed the limit to -2 instead of 0, this time, when it reaches -2, the enter key stops working

Comment: Can you include your HTML ?

Comment: You seem to bind a new event every time you call checkenterkey, why not pass the keycode into the function.  Also, not sure what you are meant to do after you have reached your max lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a few problems with your code:

1. You are appending a new event handler for `keypress` on every `keyup` and that is very bad.
2. You are using `remove()` and `after()` from JQuery which are more expensive than just laying the element and using `html()` simply.

The following solution has some code cleanup as well as remedies to the issue mentioned above.

```js
// main function for attaching the event handlers to your element
function handleChangeLineCounter(max) {
    // initial value for the counter
    $('.counter-msg-2').html(`${max} lignes restantes`);

    // keypress event to handle only allowing the needed lines
    // this code is not part of the keyup event because returning
    // false here won't prevent the key from appearing
    $('.field-line-length').keypress(function (e) {
        let diff = max - ($(this).val().match(/\n/g) || []).length;
        if (e.which === 13 && diff === 0) {
            return false;
        }
    });

    // keyup event to handle the counter display
    // this code is not part of the keypress event because the last 
    // input key would be missing 
    $('.field-line-length').keyup(function (e) {
        let diff = max - ($(this).val().match(/\n/g) || []).length;
        let msg = ((diff <= 1) ? `${diff} ligne restante` : `${diff} lignes restantes`);
        $('.counter-msg-2').html(msg);
    });
};
handleChangeLineCounter(7);
```

```css
.field-line-length {
    width: 500px;
    height: 120px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="field-line-length"></textarea>
<span class="counter-msg-2 m-r-5">
    <span class="counter_msg_2"></span>
</span>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: My pleasure, glad I could help.